# I bought DLC for Destiny and can't access it on a teen account

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

I bought the Destiny expansion pass for my Xbox Live account. My account is a teen account and Xbox is telling me

> "that purchase of this Purchase of this content is currently not
>   allowed for child and teen accounts."

The teen account does have a parent account. Is there any way to allow the teen account to access the DLC?

- The setting are: Game Ratings:T
- explicit and unrated content:blocked
- Online Gamepley:allowed
- Friend Requests:Allowed
- Purchase Content:allowed
- Voice and Text:Friends Only
- Video Comminuication:Friends Only

Comment: Are you of age in your locality?  You can try [promoting](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/security/promote-child-account) your account.  I've never heard of this issue.. especially since Destiny is rated T.  You can also try buying a physical card or a redeemable code from the vendor of your choice (Amazon, GameStop, etc.).

Comment: What are the permissions set?  All of them.

Comment: @turbo I bought a code at gamestop and all it did was put money in my microsoft account